# DataTable and bound winform textbox control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a winform with textbox controls bound to a dataset datatable. like this:

```
Me.CustomerNameTextBox.DataBindings.Add("text", MyDataSet, "tblCustomer.CustomerName")
Me.CustomerCodeTextBox.DataBindings.Add("text", MyDataSet, "tblCustomer.CustomerCode")
Me.BillAddressTextBox.DataBindings.Add("text", MyDataSet, "tblCustomer.Bill_Address")
Me.BillCityTextBox.DataBindings.Add("text", MyDataSet, "tblCustomer.Bill_City")
```

When I enter values in the textboxes and then press a button (=leave the edit) I find that table (myDataSet.Table(0)) contains all the values I entered besides for the last control/textbox that I was in.

What is the reason/solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you tabbing out of the textbox before clicking the button? Without investigating, I am suspecting tht yoou either need to require the user to exit the last textbox before clicking the buttin, which (Isuspect) is what triggers the update of the dataset.

If you click the button after completing an entry in the last text box, but instead of exiting the control using the Tab key, just mouse click the button while the control still has the focus, I believe your dataset is not updating.

I could be wrong, though. Check into it . . .

Answer (score 0):

You need a specific button's event handler so that the other buttons will not update the dataset when you update them.